# How to create a SVG file in C# and import the file in iTextSharp pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, svg, itext

I've been working in an ASP.NET MVC application (C#) in Visual Studio 2012. I've created several reports with MS Charts (to show them in a pdf file I've used iTextSharp). To show a chart as an image in iTextSharp I've used next code:

```
using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
            {

                chartCentersByYear.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);

                Byte[] newChart = chartimage.GetBuffer(); 

                var image = Image.GetInstance(newChart); 

                image.ScalePercent(50f);
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(document.LeftMargin + 40, document.BottomMargin + 95);

                document.Add(image);
            }
```

But, my charts have a very bad quality when they're zoomed on 200%. Because of that I would like to use SVG format for the charts. How can I do that in C#, using iTextSharp? The method GetInstance of the iTextSharp doesn't recognize SVG format. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, iText does not support SVG format.
This is on the long term roadmap however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and interest. However, the enum ChartImageFormat has an option: Emf. And the method GetInstance recognized Wmf format of a byte array. Have you got any idea how to convert Emf stream to Wmf? Thank you in advance.